# while using save function in mongoose it return SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await, mongoose-web-server

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/lakshKart');
}   

const kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

kittySchema.methods.speak = function speak() {
  const greeting = "Meow name is " + this.name;
  console.log(greeting);
};

const shittyKart = mongoose.model('kittyKart', kittySchema);
const helloKitty = new shittyKart({ name: 'helloKitty' });
await kittyKart.save();
```

while using save function it is giving me error await can only be used in asyn function
I don't know how to resolve it, any help.

Comment: The above code calls `kittyKart.save` but the object I believe you want is `shittyKart` or `helloKitty`

Comment: tried but yet it is giving same SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: To clarify, you tried `await helloKitty.save()` and it gave you that error?

Comment: As error message said, you can't use top level await (`await kittyKart.save();`)  in "common js" codebase. If you really want that move project to module/ESM but there will be some [downsides](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you want to save helloKitty but not kittyKart because there is no object like kittyKart here, also everything that you have written below the function will be included inside the function including the save because await function in save wants a parent async function.

So these are the correct lines of code here-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/lakshKart');
  const kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
  });
  
  kittySchema.methods.speak = function speak() {
    const greeting = "Meow name is " + this.name;
    console.log(greeting);
  };
  
  const shittyKart = mongoose.model('kittyKart', kittySchema);
  const helloKitty = new shittyKart({ name: 'helloKitty' });
  await helloKitty.save();
}
```